# What's the "Invalid syntax" in this LDAP automount command/file?

Tags: ldap, debian, automount

I want to use LDAP to automount the user's home and the nfs. I followed [this tutorial](http://uid.free.fr/Ldap/ldap.html) to configure ldap and automount. (automount information: fstype=nfs,hard,intr,nodev,nosuid,rw 192.168.0.1:/home/serveur/dupont)

```
dn: cn=dupont, ou=nfs, ou=services, dc=projet, dc=sys

objectClass: top

objectClass: automount

cn: dupont
```

I have a syntax error when trying to add this file.

```
$ ldapadd -x -f au.ldif -W -D cn=admin,dc=projet,dc=sys
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
    additional info: objectClass: value #1 invalid per syntax
```

I can't seem to find the source of this error.

```
$ ldapsearch -x

# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=projet,dc=sys> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# projet.sys
dn: dc=projet,dc=sys
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: nsalab
dc: projet

# admin, projet.sys
dn: cn=admin,dc=projet,dc=sys
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator

# people, projet.sys
dn: ou=people,dc=projet,dc=sys
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: people
description: Branche gens

# etudiants, people, projet.sys
dn: ou=etudiants,ou=people,dc=projet,dc=sys
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: etudiants
description: Branche etudiants

# personnel, people, projet.sys
dn: ou=personnel,ou=people,dc=projet,dc=sys
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: personnel
description: Branche personnel

# services, projet.sys
dn: ou=services,dc=projet,dc=sys
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: services
description: Branche services

# groupes, services, projet.sys
dn: ou=groupes,ou=services,dc=projet,dc=sys
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: groupes
description: Branche groupes

# nfs, services, projet.sys
dn: ou=nfs,ou=services,dc=projet,dc=sys
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: nfs
description: Branche nfs

# mongroupe, groupes, services, projet.sys
dn: cn=mongroupe,ou=groupes,ou=services,dc=projet,dc=sys
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixGroup
cn: mongroupe
gidNumber: 1111
description: groupe de test mongroupe

# dupont, etudiants, people, projet.sys
dn: uid=dupont,ou=etudiants,ou=people,dc=projet,dc=sys
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
uid: dupont
cn: Dupont Jean
sn: Dupont
givenName: Jean
uidNumber: 1100
gidNumber: 1111
homeDirectory: /home/aware/dupont
loginShell: /bin/bash
mail: dupont@projet.sys
l: France
ou: mongroupe

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 11
# numEntries: 10
```

---

I had to [activate the right schema](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutofsLDAP).

> The autofs-ldap.schema file needs to be converted to LDIF format. You
>   can do this with the slapcat utility as described in the
>   OpenLDAPServer guide, or you can just visit
>   launchpadlibrarian.net/55451730/autofs.ldif and grab this one
>   that's already been converted (rename it autofs-ldap.ldif and put it
>   in /etc/ldap/schema for consistency's sake).

And use `ldapadd` to import it into the database.

```
$ ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ldap/schema/autofs-ldap.ldif
```

Comment: You should post your answer in the actual answer box and self-accept it. It will help others know that your question has been solved :)

Comment: As this neither has been done by OP since May 2013 nor by you, @AnthonyMastrean, since one year later, I chose to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [activate the right schema](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutofsLDAP):

> The `autofs-ldap.schema` file needs to be converted to LDIF format. You can do this with the slapcat utility as described in the OpenLDAPServer guide, or you can just visit [`launchpadlibrarian.net/55451730/autofs.ldif`](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/55451730/autofs.ldif) and grab this one that's already been converted (rename it `autofs-ldap.ldif` and put it in `/etc/ldap/schema` for consistency's sake).

And use `ldapadd` to import it into the database.

```
$ ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ldap/schema/autofs-ldap.ldif
```